# How to get My Zero Member Github Organization Back?

Tags: github

[Prelude]

I had my own account at Github.

Created a new Organization for a client of which I was the only member.

My work took a different turn and I started working a lot on different projects and I decided to turn my account into an Organization.  I did so, and when doing so left all organization to which I belonged...

[Problem]

Now my other Organization has 0 (zero) Members and I cannot login to it to add myself back again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Contact GitHub support.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to contact github support faster than support@github.com??? This is now urgent, I need to get their attention.